# Displays [object Object] instead of label name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syntax

I'm new to JS and having some difficulties with the syntax. Could you please advise what is wrong with my code syntax since it returns this on my page instead of the label name/id value:

```
[object Object]
```

My code snippet:

{`The success message is ${(firstValue || secondValue) ? <FormattedMessage id="success.label.name" /> : '-'}`}

Comment: You are probably displaying an object instead of an string. Can u add minimal code for us to understand.

Comment: What is the `$` doing. Try removing it

Comment: Currently it's like this:

{`The success message is: ${(firstValue || secondValue) ? <FormattedMessage id="success.label.name" /> : '-'} `}

Can't remove $ it allows to add embedded expressions

Comment: Try to console `success.label.name` and see what you getting inside that. If its a string or an object

Answer (score 0):

You displayed object.

You can try like this. Example

```
valObj = {
    "name": 'value',
    "id": 'value'
}

Object.entries(valObj).map(([key, val]) => 
                <h2 key={key}>{key}: {val}</h2>)
```